# I can't center texts in Android Studio

Tags: android, text, textview

I made the changes you said, but it still looks the same. I leave my code and screenshot. The texts are still at the top and nested inside each other. (Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc malesuada sed lacus sit amet cursus. Nullam eleifend, mauris ac hendrerit gravida, ipsum neque ullamcorper tortor, id efficitur odio justo eget nibh.)

[HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59Xf4.png)

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="X values"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Y value:"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Z value:"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

`gravity` attribute is used to describe gravity of content of given view.

for changing gravity within parent, you need to use `layout_gravity` (in most layouts)

in most cases you would set them both, so if the text inside textview is longer, it will be centered within itself

```xml
<TextView
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:gravity="center" />
```

in case of `ConstraintLayout` you need to add constraints of both sides of view to the parent

```
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
```

Comment: I added the android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" code to all textviex sections, but there was no improvement

Comment: You have ConstraintLayout as a parent layout, it have its own layout rules. I have added info about that

Answer (score 0):

If you work with constraint layout as the parent view, you have to anchor your textviews vertically and horizontally to the sides of your constraint layout frame. Also, you should use "blueprint-mode" in your XML viewer in order to see overlapping views better and can organize them better.

You can find detailed information about the mentioned things here:
https://abhiandroid.com/ui/constraintlayout